# How to calculate time complexity of given algorithm ( ridge regression)?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, time-complexity, big-o

i have following expression and i need to calculate time complexity of this algorithm. Could anybody help to get correct time complexity of this algorithm.

```
% save a matrix-vector multiply
Atb = A'*b;

% cache the factorization (using cholesky factorization)
[L U] = factor(A, a);  

for( k = 0; k < maxiter; k++) 
    {
         x^k+1 = (A^TA + a* I)^-1 (A^Tb + a (z^k - u^k))^T
    }
```

Where A = mxn matrix and n>>>m, b,u,z = nx1 vectors, I = identity matrix and a=0.001

Comment: Are `^k` supposed to be superscripts / subscripts instead of exponents (what's the exponent of a vector)? Also, are `A` and `b` constants (if they are then inversion and transposition can be performed outside the loop).

Comment: yes, ^k is superscript. A and b are calculated as A^tb outside.

Comment: `(A^T*A + a*I)^-1` should also be cacheable, so the complexity is just `O(inversion) + maxiter * O(transpose + multiply)` (assuming that inversion is more expensive than other operations).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog O(inversion) + maxiter * O(transpose + multiply)?

Comment: They are just placeholder names for the real complexity functions of each operation (which are implementation dependent).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what is inversion, transpose and multiply in my above problem?

Comment: If `A` is mxn and `b` is nx1 , then for `A^Tb` you have `nxm * nx1`.

Comment: Problems with dimensions also manifests itself in the right half. After taking transpose of vector in the second multiplier you have `nxn * 1xn`.

Comment: What have *you* tried so far? Share your ideas / findings.

Comment: Yola would write complete answer for me of above code. because i did not understand it clearly. could you also recommend some reference material related to it?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what is the final answer for this? is this answer correct O(maxiter * (mn^2 + n)) or O( n^3 + maxiter (m*n^2 + n ))?

Comment: Depends on what algorithms are used for those operations, especially multiplication and inversion, and how large `maxiter` is

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you can use something like `std::max`

Comment: @Yola could you explain what you mean by that? How does `std::max` help in this situation?

Comment: You are telling that you use Cholesky factorization, but for my knowledge it's only applied for square matrices.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you are asking for how big is `maxiter`, so you can use `max` to answer w/o knowing it.

Comment: Yes, it converts into LU form, but it works for square matrices. Can you tell where did you get this code, or what is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Yola  you may right but would you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The most computationally intensive operation here is matrix inversion, so it depends on how you implement this operation. If we assume that you implemented with a Gauss–Jordan algorithm which [takes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) `O(n^3)` then overall complexity is `O(maxiter * n^3)`. Here i take into account that `n` is bigger than `m` (`A^T*A` takes `O(m*n^2)`).

If you calculate `(A^T*A + a*I)^-1` and `A^Tb` outside then you are left with

```
Inv * (Atb + a(z^k - u^k))^T
```

which is `O(n^2)` because you need to multiply nxn matrix by nx1 vector while addition and subtraction take `O(n)`.

Still, you have some inconsistencies in sizes which i described in comments for the question.

Comment: i am using cholesky factorization for matrix A.

Comment: A^TA is of size m x m. The workload to compute the product, nm², is larger than for inversion, m³.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, but A is `mxn` (as it is written in the quesion), so A^T is `nxm` and A^TA is `nxm * mxn`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i also noticed some inconsistencies in the question. You can read my comments to it.

Comment: @yola what is the final answer for this? is this answer correct O(maxiter * (mn^2 + n)) or O( n^3 + maxiter (m*n^2 + n ))?

Comment: @Humayoo there are some inconsistencies in your question. Could you please tell from where you took this code?